# UITextView delegates disables Scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

when setting the delegate of my UITextView, i can't scroll and when adding new lines the scrollview isn't scrolling down

The UITextView is inside a UITableViewCell inside a UITableView

my code is

```
class groupProfile_DescriptionCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {    

@IBOutlet weak var tvEdit: UITextView!

override func initCell() {
    ...
    tvEdit.scrollEnabled = true
    tvEdit.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 1):

after some try&error i found out that adding `UIScrollViewDelegate`, and the `scrollViewDidScroll` function to my class fixxed my problem. Hope it helps someone else having this problem